# Sending data to controller when switching tabs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

My app has 4 tabs. On the 4th tab, there is an option to "Sign in" to the app, which takes the user to the Sign In controller. When the user signs in, I want to switch the user back to the 1st tab, which I do with the following code:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

However, I want to refresh the content on the 1st tab after the user is logged in (because the content is user-specific). This means that I need to pass some data when the user switches tabs to let the controller in the 1st tab know to refresh the data.

How would I send data to the 1st tab when switching between tabs to refresh the content? Or is there a better way around this?

Comment: is the first controller in each tab a navigation controller? or view controller?

Comment: @VincentJoy A navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

[image] [image]

You can either do it by using notification/observer or by using delegate pattern.

Because it seems to be an one to one relationship you should probably use the delegate pattern as notification and observer are use for one to many relationships.

1. Create a protocol right above your 4th tab view controller code. The parameters of this function will be the data that you will transfer from one ViewController to another. In this example I transfer the text of a textField where the user can put its name :

   ```
   protocol SelectionDelegate {
       func didTapChoice(name: String)
   }
   ```
2. Add a delegate variable within your 4th tab view controller:

   ```
   var selectionDelegate: SelectionDelegate!
   ```
3. Call the function of your delegate variable within an @IBAction:

   ```
   selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(name: textField.text!)
   tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
   ```
4. Assign the selection delegate to the 1st viewcontroller in viewDidLoad() of the 2nd viewcontroller:

   ```
   selectionDelegate = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? SelectionDelegate
   ```
5. Add an extension to the bottom of your 1st tab view controller implementing the protocol function:

   ```
   extension FirstTabViewController: SelectionDelegate {
       func didTapChoice(name: String) {
           displayLabel.text = name
       }
   }
   ```

Here is the result for the first viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTabViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension FirstTabViewController: SelectionDelegate {
    func didTapChoice(name: String) {
        displayLabel.text = name
    }
}
```

Here is the result for the second viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

protocol SelectionDelegate {
    func didTapChoice(name: String)
}

class SecondTabViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectionDelegate: SelectionDelegate!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func goToFirstTabButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectionDelegate.didTapChoice(name: textField.text!)
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectionDelegate = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? SelectionDelegate
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just subclass UITabBarController, create a variable there, and then retrieve that variable when switching to the first tab?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method in your first tab's view controller (say **yourCustomMethod()**), then you can access that method from fourth tab's view controller using :-

```
    if let navigationController = self.tabBarController?.childViewControllers[0],
        let firstVC = navigationController.childViewControllers[0] as? FlightsHomeViewController {

        let yourData = ["username": "something"]
        firstVC.yourCustomMethod(data: yourData)
    }
```

Comment: This would probably works but is not considered as an ideal solution:
https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Answer (score 0):

1. In the **first VC**. listen a **login** notification.
2. In the **Login VC**. When user did login. post the **login** notification.